# Recommendation of Stack Exchange-like website for self-help

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for self-help? I tried posting on cogsci but they closed my question claiming it wasn't the right place.

Comment: Oops. I should have browsed through the full list of websites at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: FYI, as it is phrased your question on cgosi isn't a good fit for any Stack Exchange site. It's very open-ended and will lead to everyone posting their own tips & tricks.

Comment: Mmm. True that that is the style of stack exchange. Sometimes asking a vague question allows people to ask me clarification questions which in turn helps me become more specific in my question. I wrote down the details as far as I could process in head when I wrote the question

Comment: I don't know the personal productivity website, but from what I read in your question on cogsci, I'd say your question could be closed as a duplicate of the _entire site_ :-) There's nothing really specific in it AFAICT.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree on this one. I feel I gave at least some details about what I wanted answered. You may not see it that way and I am not gonna force you to see it my way

Comment: If you're looking for something *similar* to Stack Exchange, but for self help, you could try asking at SE Software Recommendations.

Comment: How can you have a Q&A about self-help? Would they all be self-answered questions that only relate to the OP? What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be a [Personal Productivity](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296) site, which was closed after 6 years in beta since it could not get enough activity.

I'm afraid that currently there are no sites in Stack Exchange fitting for "self help". One might re-suggest the above, this time brining some existing community to support it and give it the initial boost it needs, but otherwise, attempt to just re-try it will fail.